# How much weight does previous research experience carry for an admit to MS in computer science?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I don’t have publications from research projects or internships. However, my letters of recommendation may state about my research experience. I am applying to universities in the USA. I have all the coursework prerequisites.

Comment: What does LORs mean?

Comment: @user2768 Letter of Recommendation

Comment: Is it a taught MS or a research-based MS? What are the entry requirements?

Comment: What country is the MS in?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper USA

Comment: @O.R.Mapper USA

Comment: As @user2768 was asking, is there a research component to this Master's program (for example, do you have to write a thesis?), or is it purely course-work-based?

Comment: @user2768 I'll be opting for a thesis but I need not mention it now in my application packet

Comment: It sounds like @BlackSwan is applying for a taught MS, rather than a research-based MS. So, I don't think research experience is a prerequisite. Nonetheless, the OP should check the entry requirements, which should state whether research experience is required. (If it isn't, then it doesn't carry much weight.)